# Do/while loop in node.js to get total tweet counts only runs once

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, do-while, node-twitter

When making a get request to twitter api, it returns all the tweets in the array `tweets.statuses`. We can find the total tweet counts using `tweets.statuses.length`. In one request it can only return a maximum of 100 tweets even if there are 1000s of tweets available.

Similarly the metadata is returned in the array `tweets.search_metadata` which looks like the object as shown below. Here count is the count that is passed to the twitter api and not the count of tweets returned.

```
{ completed_in: 0.13,
  max_id: 1049894626625286100,
  max_id_str: '1049894626625286144',
  next_results: '?    max_id=1049894470475485183&q=apple&count=100&include_entities=1',
  query: 'apple',
  refresh_url: '?since_id=1049894626625286144&q=apple&include_entities=1',
  count: 100,
  since_id: 0,
  since_id_str: '0' }
```

In the metadata above, we can check to see if `next_results` exists. If it does, it means there are more results available so we can make the request to twitter api again and again , by passing it a new max_id every time, until next_results is null i.e. it does not exist when the last batch of results are returned. Every time next_results exists a new max_id is generated which can be used to fetch the next 100 tweets.

To solve this I am using a do while loop in which the code block i.e. the twitter api request will run at least once before check the condition i.e. if `next_results` exists.

The problem is that my do while loop only runs once even though `next_results` is still available and not null. What am i doing wrong!

My node.js code looks like this:

```js
require('dotenv').load();

var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  bearer_token: process.env.TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN
});

var url = 'apple';
var totalCount = 0;
var resultsExist, maxid, isEqualsToLocation, andLocation;

do {
    client.get('search/tweets', {q: url, count:100, max_id: maxid})
    .then(function(tweets){
        console.log('next_results: ',tweets.search_metadata.next_results)
        console.log('totalCount: ',tweets.statuses.length)
        console.log(tweets.search_metadata)
        totalCount += tweets.statuses.length
        console.log(totalCount)
        console.log(tweets.search_metadata.next_results == null)
        if(tweets.search_metadata.next_results != null){
            resultsExist = tweets.search_metadata.next_results
            console.log('result is', resultsExist)
            isEqualsToLocation = resultsExist.indexOf('=');
            andLocation = resultsExist.indexOf('&');
            maxid = resultsExist.substring(isEqualsToLocation+1,andLocation);
            console.log(maxid)
        } else {
            resultsExist = tweets.search_metadata.next_results
        }
        console.log(resultsExist == null)
    })
}

while (resultsExist != null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your scenario, at the first, client will be created, then "do {" line execute, then "client.get(..." line execute, then "while (resultsExist != null)" execute that is false. After all, when your response return from twitter, call back function "function(tweets){" will be execute. so your do/while loop will be run just 1 time.
I don't have any twitter customer key for test, but below code must be work fine

```
require('dotenv').load();

var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = new Twitter({
consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
bearer_token: process.env.TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN
});

var url = 'apple';
var max_id;


async function getAllTwits(q, count, max_id){
    var totalCount = 0;
    var resultsExist, maxid, isEqualsToLocation, andLocation;
    maxid = max_id
    do {
        var tweets = await client.get('search/tweets', {q: q, count:count, max_id: maxid});

        console.log('next_results: ',tweets.search_metadata.next_results)
        console.log('totalCount: ',tweets.statuses.length)
        console.log(tweets.search_metadata)
        totalCount += tweets.statuses.length
        console.log(totalCount)
        console.log(tweets.search_metadata.next_results == null)
        if(tweets.search_metadata.next_results != null){
            resultsExist = tweets.search_metadata.next_results
            console.log('result is', resultsExist)
            isEqualsToLocation = resultsExist.indexOf('=');
            andLocation = resultsExist.indexOf('&');
            maxid = resultsExist.substring(isEqualsToLocation+1,andLocation);
            console.log(maxid)
        } else {
            resultsExist = tweets.search_metadata.next_results
        }
        console.log(resultsExist == null)
    }
    while (resultsExist != null);
}


getAllTwits(url, 100, max_id);
```

Comment: thanks a ton. But i don't understand why is async await required here!

Comment: You should wait for client.get response if you want using do/while loop, so you need await. Await can use in async function.